# is there a way to access model attributes while using with method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

hey guys i have a problem.
im trying to eagerload my basket items by defining a scope:

```php
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    $builder->with(['product']);
}
```

and my product relation inside basket model is like below:

```php
public function product()
{
    if ($this->used_product_id) {
        return $this->belongsTo(UsedProduct::class, 'used_product_id', 'id');
    } else {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

but the problem is when using **with()** *$this->used_product_id* returns **null** and i cant get access to my current model attributes.
do you have any solution?

Comment: Where did you define the scope?

Comment: thanks for your reply! in my model @IGP

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want with eager loading. The problem is that the model would never know whether the product is new or used until it fetches the Basket.

Comment: so what is the best way to eager load products of a basket? @mankowitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
class Basket extends Model
{

    public function newProduct()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }

    public function usedProduct()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UsedProduct::class, 'used_product_id', 'id');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->usedProduct ?? $this->newProduct ?? null;
    }

}
```

To make sure that the products are eager loaded, you'd have to load it with both products, like

```
Basket::with(['newProduct','usedProduct'])->get()
```

Comment: you made my day @mankowitz! 

Answer (score 1):

You could define your scope like an [anonymous global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#anonymous-global-scopes)

```php
class Basket extends Model
{
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('withProduct', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->with('product');
        });
    }

    public function product()
    {
        if ($this->used_product_id) {
            return $this->belongsTo(UsedProduct::class, 'used_product_id', 'id');
        } else {
            return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
        }
    }
}
```

Or use the `$with` property.

```php
class Basket extends Model
{
    /**
     * The relations to eager load on every query.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['product'];

    public function product()
    {
        if ($this->used_product_id) {
            return $this->belongsTo(UsedProduct::class, 'used_product_id', 'id');
        } else {
            return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but the problem is my first statement which is `if($this->used_product_id)` always returns false. because `$this->used_product_id` return s **null** @IGP

Comment: Does `used_product_id` has a value or is it unset?

Comment: no all of my basket attributes are unset @IGP

Comment: Then why is it a problem= It's working as intended.